# Can't switch 3 languages: English-US (as base), Russian and Ukrainian. Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (desktop:Unity)

Tags: unity, keyboard, keyboard-layout, language-support

In answers with tag "keyboard-layout" I don't found my case so have to ask.
I'm using three languages: English-US (as base), Russian and Ukrainian installed. Ubuntu 14.04 Trusty (desktop:Unity) allow me switch English-Russian (Win+space) and only this two are present in language-icon menu.

"Text entry settings" doesn't appears  at all.

In dconf setting source in [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru'), ('xkb', 'ua')] revert to [('xkb', 'us'), ('xkb', 'ru')].

In "System Settings >> Language Support >> Default input method" settled "none" and not changeable.

My demand is English first so I want see English menu etc., but I'm fluent in with Russian and Ukrainian and develop soft for this languages.

In Window I'm easy use this three and how can I do it with Ubuntu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't see *Text Entry* under *System Settings*, some packages are probably missing. To fix it, open a terminal window and do:

```
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Then (at least at next login) *Text Entry* ought to be available. Add the input sources of your choice there.